# Effective Estimates for Generalized Merten's Theorem

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Fix $r>1$. I would like to obtain strong effective estimates for $$\prod_{p\leq x}\left(1-p^{-r}\right).$$ Certainly this product tends to $1/\zeta(r)$ as $x\to\infty$, but I am more interested in how quickly it does so. I assume I could adapt the proof of Merten's Third theorem (which is the case $r=1$) in order to get some reasonable asymptotic estimate. However, since I am more interested in effective estimates (and I don't want to spend an enormous amount of time trying to optimize constants), I was hoping someone might know of a reference for this.

Comment: For $r > 1$ there is the trivial bound $\sum_{p \ge x+1} p^{-r} <\sum_{n \ge x+1} n^{-r} < \frac{x^{1-r}}{1-r}$ and Merten's theorem (as well as the prime number theorem) implies $\sum_{p \ge x+1} p^{-r} < C \sum_{n \ge x+1} \frac{n^{-r}}{\log n} < C \frac{x^{1-r}}{(1-r)\log x}$. Conclude by taking the logarithm of your product.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you. I was being silly. I see now that this is straightforward with a Stieltjes integral and PNT.